# How to import a font with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to import a font with:

```
@font-face {
font-family: Manifiesto;
src: url(MANIFIESTO.ttf);
}

div {
font-family: Manifiesto; 
}
```

The font file name is: MANIFIESTO.ttf.

I uploaded the font file to the same folder as index.html but i cannot use this font, i see a default font instead.

I'm missing something?
Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to put it in quotes as a string.

Comment: And your css is on .... ? the path must be relative to the CSS file

Comment: make a webfont out of it. you usually can't just upload your own file. use this tool, it will built out a cross-browser stack. https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: I will close this question as duplicate, it's too vague and maybe following the comments and the answers on the dup you will fin the solution if not please tag me to reopen and make more clear what have you tried after the info provided

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Manifiesto';
    src: url('MANIFIESTO.ttf') format('truetype');
}

div {
    font-family: 'Manifiesto'; 
}
```

Comment: The quotes aren't necessary. Advised, but not necessary https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#family-name-value